# Zend redirects to json response

Tags: json, zend-framework

I'm making a POST request, using ajax, to a Zend Controller.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg.success){
                   //doesn't reach here. I'm getting redirected
                    console.log('success');
                }
            }
        });
```

In zend, I have the following line:

```
$this->jsonResponse(array('success' => true, 'embed' => 'some text here'));
```

My problem is that I'm getting redirected to the json response page (that's the actual page) which contains the response. The response is correct, but I don't want to be redirected. I don't know what's happening and why is this happening.

Comment: Please provide some more details regarding your code.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola POST request to the same page in javascript with ajax. I don't know what to say more.

Comment: Why don't you try **json action helper**? : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.json

Answer (score 0):

In controller write these codes

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); //to disable layout
$this->view->jsonResponse = json_encode(array(
'success' => true,
'embed' => 'some text here'
)); // encode array
```

And in view write this line

```
echo $this->jsonResponse;
```